# Value was either too large or too small for an Int32 - Facebook & dotnetopenauth

Tags: c#, asp.net, facebook, dotnetopenauth

I am trying to get a sample project to work with dotnetopenauth and facebook.

I have this code

```
namespace OAuthClient
{
    using System;
    using System.Configuration;
    using System.Net;
    using System.Web;
    using DotNetOpenAuth.ApplicationBlock;
    using DotNetOpenAuth.ApplicationBlock.Facebook;
    using DotNetOpenAuth.OAuth2;

public partial class Facebook : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    private static readonly FacebookClient client = new FacebookClient
    {
        ClientIdentifier = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["facebookAppID"],
        ClientSecret = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["facebookAppSecret"],
    };

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        IAuthorizationState authorization = client.ProcessUserAuthorization();

        if (authorization == null)
        {
            var authorizationState = new AuthorizationState()
            {
                Callback = new Uri(Request.Url, "http://localhost:3000/Facebook.aspx/")
            };
            client.PrepareRequestUserAuthorization(authorizationState).Send();
        }
        else
        {
            var request = WebRequest.Create("https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=" + Uri.EscapeDataString(authorization.AccessToken));
            using (var response = request.GetResponse())
            {
                using (var responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
                {
                    var graph = FacebookGraph.Deserialize(responseStream);
                    this.nameLabel.Text = HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(graph.Name);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

So I make request first to facebook and that works nice and fine. I then get a response back from them and it goes into the else statement.

However I run into this error( happens on var `graph = FacebookGraph.Deserialize(responseStream`) )

```
Server Error in '/' Application.
Value was either too large or too small for an Int32.
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.OverflowException: Value was either too large or too small for an Int32.

Source Error:

Line 49:            }
Line 50: 
Line 51:            return (FacebookGraph)jsonSerializer.ReadObject(jsonStream);
Line 52:        }
Line 53:    }


Source File: C:\Users\user\Downloads\DotNetOpenAuth-3.5.0.10357\DotNetOpenAuth-3.5.0.10357\Samples\DotNetOpenAuth.ApplicationBlock\Facebook\FacebookGraph.cs    Line: 51

Stack Trace:

[OverflowException: Value was either too large or too small for an Int32.]
   System.Number.ParseInt32(String s, NumberStyles style, NumberFormatInfo info) +7471379
   System.Runtime.Serialization.Json.XmlJsonReader.ParseInt(String value, NumberStyles style) +68

[XmlException: The value '100000325104290' cannot be parsed as the type 'Int32'.]
   System.Runtime.Serialization.Json.XmlJsonReader.ParseInt(String value, NumberStyles style) +259
   System.Runtime.Serialization.Json.XmlJsonReader.ReadContentAsInt() +22
   System.Xml.XmlDictionaryReader.ReadElementContentAsInt() +62
   System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlReaderDelegator.ReadElementContentAsInt() +26
   ReadFacebookGraphFromJson(XmlReaderDelegator , XmlObjectSerializerReadContextComplexJson , XmlDictionaryString , XmlDictionaryString[] ) +628
   System.Runtime.Serialization.Json.JsonClassDataContract.ReadJsonValueCore(XmlReaderDelegator jsonReader, XmlObjectSerializerReadContextComplexJson context) +58
   System.Runtime.Serialization.Json.JsonDataContract.ReadJsonValue(XmlReaderDelegator jsonReader, XmlObjectSerializerReadContextComplexJson context) +31
   System.Runtime.Serialization.Json.XmlObjectSerializerReadContextComplexJson.ReadDataContractValue(DataContract dataContract, XmlReaderDelegator reader) +25
   System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerReadContext.InternalDeserialize(XmlReaderDelegator reader, String name, String ns, DataContract& dataContract) +128
   System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerReadContext.InternalDeserialize(XmlReaderDelegator xmlReader, Type declaredType, DataContract dataContract, String name, String ns) +39
   System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerReadContextComplex.InternalDeserialize(XmlReaderDelegator xmlReader, Type declaredType, DataContract dataContract, String name, String ns) +32
   System.Runtime.Serialization.Json.DataContractJsonSerializer.InternalReadObject(XmlReaderDelegator xmlReader, Boolean verifyObjectName) +1048152
   System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializer.ReadObjectHandleExceptions(XmlReaderDelegator reader, Boolean verifyObjectName) +98

[SerializationException: There was an error deserializing the object of type DotNetOpenAuth.ApplicationBlock.Facebook.FacebookGraph. The value '100000325104290' cannot be parsed as the type 'Int32'.]
   System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializer.ReadObjectHandleExceptions(XmlReaderDelegator reader, Boolean verifyObjectName) +496
   System.Runtime.Serialization.Json.DataContractJsonSerializer.ReadObject(XmlDictionaryReader reader) +43
   System.Runtime.Serialization.Json.DataContractJsonSerializer.ReadObject(Stream stream) +67
   DotNetOpenAuth.ApplicationBlock.Facebook.FacebookGraph.Deserialize(Stream jsonStream) in C:\Users\user\Downloads\DotNetOpenAuth-3.5.0.10357\DotNetOpenAuth-3.5.0.10357\Samples\DotNetOpenAuth.ApplicationBlock\Facebook\FacebookGraph.cs:51
   OAuthClient.Facebook.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Users\user\Downloads\DotNetOpenAuth-3.5.0.10357\DotNetOpenAuth-3.5.0.10357\Samples\OAuthClient\Facebook.aspx.cs:39
   System.Web.Util.CalliHelper.EventArgFunctionCaller(IntPtr fp, Object o, Object t, EventArgs e) +14
   System.Web.Util.CalliEventHandlerDelegateProxy.Callback(Object sender, EventArgs e) +35
   System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +99
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +50
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +627


Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:2.0.50727.4952; ASP.NET Version:2.0.50727.4955
```

So this class gets called

```
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------
// <copyright file="FacebookGraph.cs" company="Andrew Arnott">
//     Copyright (c) Andrew Arnott. All rights reserved.
// </copyright>
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------

namespace DotNetOpenAuth.ApplicationBlock.Facebook {
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.IO;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Runtime.Serialization;
    using System.Runtime.Serialization.Json;
    using System.Text;

    [DataContract]
    public class FacebookGraph {
        private static DataContractJsonSerializer jsonSerializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(FacebookGraph));

        [DataMember(Name = "id")]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name = "name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name = "first_name")]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name = "last_name")]
        public string LastName { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name = "link")]
        public Uri Link { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name = "birthday")]
        public string Birthday { get; set; }

        public static FacebookGraph Deserialize(string json) {
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(json)) {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("json");
            }

            return Deserialize(new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json)));
        }

        public static FacebookGraph Deserialize(Stream jsonStream) {
            if (jsonStream == null) {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("jsonStream");
            }

            return (FacebookGraph)jsonSerializer.ReadObject(jsonStream);
        }
    }
}
```

Has something changed with the AccessToken? Are they bigger now?

I know this sample is using an older version than the current version of dotnetopenauth but the current version does not include facebook

[dotnetopenauth CTP](http://sourceforge.net/projects/dnoa/files/CTP/OAuth2/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the Facebook id should be Int64 instead of Int32 now.

Take a look at [this change](https://github.com/AArnott/dotnetopenid/commit/2d70a89d9d8f0471cde82ae45f7fc004b9f4f839)