# How To Restrict Integer To Allow Up To 10 Digits

Tags: c#, regex, asp.net-web-api

I want to restrict an integer to allow maximum 10 digits .i.e from 0 to any number(XXXXXXXXXX)

**I am using C# and .NET Web API**

In my Class(.cs) file i have used like this

```
[RegularExpression(@"^\d{1,10}$", ErrorMessage = "Invalid RequestedN")] 
[Display(Name = "RequestedN")]
public int RequestedN { get; set; }
```

I will get a JSON response on clicking my submit button..I will validate that JSON(object) by validating ModelState in Controller...

When I enter 11 digits it is showing message as below

**"JSON integer 91234567890 is too large or small for an Int32. Path 'Quotas[0].RequestedN', line 1, position 81."**

But I want message as "Invalid RequestedN"

I have tried another RegularExpression as below but no use.

```
^([1-9]|([1-9][0-9])|([1-9][0-9][0-9])|([1-9][0-9][0-9][0-9])|([1-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9])|\d{6}|\d{7}|\d{8}|\d{9}|\d{10})$
```

Suggest any idea or solution to this problem

Comment: Perhaps, you should use `public long RequestedN { get; set; }`. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4839511/value-was-either-too-large-or-too-small-for-an-int32-facebook-dotnetopenauth

Comment: Are you sure you want to store/process this value as an `int`? Since the range of an `int` is -2147483648 to 2147483647 it is *already* incapable of storing any integer with more than 10 digits (and some with 10 digits). Perhaps you want a `string` instead? (I.e. will you actually be performing any maths on this number, or is it actually, logically, a string of digits?)

Comment: ok, fine . Now I want to limit int 32 to accept from 0 to  2147483647.Then what will be the possible regular expression that matches all values from 0 to  2147483647

Comment: Are you going to be performing mathematical calculations on this number?  If not, it should be a string.

Comment: No mathematical calculations,instead check whether user entered a valid integer value with in its range and if valid store that value  in database.

Answer (score 3):

You will have to use Int64:

> Int64 is an immutable value type that represents signed integers with values that range from negative 9,223,372,036,854,775,808 (which is represented by the Int64::MinValue constant) through positive 9,223,372,036,854,775,807 (which is represented by the Int64::MaxValue constant. The .NET Framework also includes an unsigned 64-bit integer value type, UInt64, which represents values that range from 0 to 18,446,744,073,709,551,615.

So convert your number to Int64 and then you can use your expression: ^\d{1,10}$

Comment: ok, fine . Now I want to limit int 32 to accept from 0 to  2147483647.Then what will be the possible regular expression that matches all values from 0 to  2147483647

Answer (score 2):

Because the value you entered is greater than the value an Int32 can hold.

See link : [Int32](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.maxvalue(v=vs.110).aspx)

> The value of this constant is 2,147,483,647; that is, hexadecimal
>   0x7FFFFFFF.

If you want to support ten digits, please consider another datatype.

Maybe [Int64](http://%20Int64.MaxValue%20Field) which is the [long](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ctetwysk.aspx) data type.

Comment: ok, fine . Now I want to limit int 32 to accept from 0 to  2147483647.Then what will be the possible regular expression that matches all values from 0 to  2147483647

Comment: That really is a new question. However, it's quite simple to limit to 1999999999 with `^1?\d{0,9}$`. Matching a maximum of 2147483647 is considerably more complex. It's certainly possible and there are online regex generators for the task.